# How to make custom pages from scratch WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a task to create a website on WordPress but the website itself doesn't have to include any bloggy features. (I want to add recent news section at the bottom of the home page)
Basically, I'm writing the whole website in notepad++. Everything is placed in a theme folder (like a new WordPress template).

I don't want to use WordPress page creator because it is very limited. I want to write every particular page on my own in a text editor.

But unfortunately, when I include header&footer in `index.php`, and place the page code in for example promotions.php (created in notepad++ - not WordPress page editor). Like: `<div class="text-bar">Promotions!</div>` into `promotions.php` it doesn't show this div. It shows only header and footer. Which was included in `index.php` with Wordpress functions `get_header()` and `get_footer()`.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You required to create page template for create your own page in WordPress.

For Full documentation of create page template, Go to [Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-templates/)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you right. You have to follow the template hierarchy. To create a home page with your complete custom DOM or markup. Create a new file name front-page.php. This will default as your home page template. No posts queried.

Then add text as below:

```
<?php

/*Home Page template*/

get_header();?>

<div class="text-bar">Promotions!</div>
<?php get_footer();
```